# Laptop connects via Wifi but only if a PC is not connected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My work laptop will connect via wifi no problem until I add a hardwired PC to the router - at which point the laptop wireless fails to connect. The PC once wired connects to internet fine. I also have a chromebook on the wireless network and it stays up regardless of whether the PC is connected.

This all used to work no problem for months - it only failed after I upgraded a PC to Windows 10 a few days ago.

I've updated all NIC drivers.

My router's DHCP is at 192.168.1.1 and I have reserved .2 to .10 so it only allocates .11 onward

The laptop IP is set to 192.168.1.10 (out of the range of the dhcp, I did this to guarantee no conflict even though I never received a conflict notice)
The hard-wired PC is using dhcp and is currently 192.168.1.12

Here is my working ipconfig /all for the wireless card :

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9002WB-1NG Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E0-CA-94-F2-9A-84
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::bcdf:8b77:a056:8ba0%3(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 165726868
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-BC-5E-A8-E0-CA-94-F2-9A-84
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Here's what things look like after I add the PC back to the network:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig /renew

Windows IP Configuration

No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 5 while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 7 while it has its media disconnected.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig /all

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9002WB-1NG Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E0-CA-94-F2-9A-84
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::bcdf:8b77:a056:8ba0%3(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 165726868
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-BC-5E-A8-E0-CA-94-F2-9A-84
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping 192.168.1.1

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1513ms TTL=64
```

Windows Event logs - very frustrating there is no detailed info about what causes the wifi to go from "working" to "non-working". Here is the only clue I get:

```
Name resolution for the name www.google.com timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.
```

Comment: when I add the PC to the network, it takes roughly 10 minutes for the laptop's connection to die.

Comment: yes i answered my own question - i am putting all this info here in case it helps someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was rolling *back* my NIC driver - i found this on another site after hours of searching.

adding the following to facilitate keyword searches in case it helps anyone else:
toshiba qosmio
Qualcomm Atheros AR9002WB-1NG Wireless Network Adapter
Here's what you want to see in Device Manager (for windows 10, on network with multiple windows 10 machines):

```
driver version: 10.0.0.326
driver date: 2015-09-06 (not sure where this date comes from)
```

How to get the above:

```
Search for: TC70178000B.exe
You will land here: http://support.toshiba.com/sscontent?contentId=4004141
and find:
Version: 10.0.0.263.0.b3264_wCAT_wINF
Posted Date: 2013-10-17 (not sure why this date is different than above)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd to me that your router is the DNS server. I could be wrong, but I think the DNS server is usually at your ISP. Check what DNS server your wired PC is using. If you have a static IP on your laptop, you have to also enter a valid DNS server, whereas using DHCP will detect and assign it automatically.

However, I would expect an invalid DNS server to prevent you from connecting at any time, regardless of whether the wired PC is connected. Try pinging the wired PC's IP address from the laptop. If that doesn't work, DNS isn't the problem.

Some other things to try:

- Power cycle the router
- Update the router firmware
- Use the Windows "diagnose network connectivity" thingy
- Use Wireshark to see if the DNS queries are going out, and if you're getting a reply from the DNS server.

Comment: thanks for the advice - i tried almost all those things at some point. not wireshark though

for DNS - yes my router IP is also my DNS server - that's what IPCONFIG shows on all working DHCP enabled devices - fwiw i am verizon fios on a coax router in case that helps explain?